# ggplot in R to add significance asterisk vs control group over multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have barplots, but would like to run a Wilcox.test within each "grp1" comparing the bars to the control for that group, and then putting an asterix if it is significant.

I've seen "compare_means" to get the comparisons, but I'm trying to make it automated and not so manual. Would "geom_signif" or "stat_compare_means" do this? Can someone help with this? Thank you very much.

I need the comparison to be made using the full dataset, not just the means (which is only one value per bar). I added a line at the end of the code running one of the comparisons so you can see where I need the p-values from.

```
y <- c(runif(100,0,4.5),runif(100,3,6),runif(100,4,7))
grp1 <- sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size = 300, replace = TRUE)
grp2 <- rep(c("High","Med","Contrl"),each=100)
dataset <- data.frame(y,grp1,grp2)

means <- aggregate(y~grp1+grp2,data=dataset,mean)
sd <- aggregate(y~grp1+grp2,data=dataset,function(x){sd(x)})

means.all <- merge(sd,means,by=c("grp1","grp2"))
names(means.all)[3:4] <- c("sd","y.mean")

library(ggplot2)
p<- ggplot(means.all, aes(x=grp1, y=y.mean, fill=grp2))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y.mean-sd, ymax=y.mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
p

compare_means(y~grp2,data = dataset[dataset$grp1=="A",],method="wilcox.test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the optimal way but you can create a list splitting the data and applying the `stat_compare_means()` function individually at each level of your data. After that you can arrange the plots in one using `patchwork`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork)
#Split data
List <- split(means.all,means.all$grp1)
#Function for plot
myfun <- function(x)
{
  #Ref group
  rg <- paste0(unique(x$grp1),'.','Contrl')
  #Plot
  G <- ggplot(x, aes(x=interaction(grp1,grp2), y=y.mean, fill=grp2))+ 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
             position=position_dodge()) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y.mean-sd, ymax=y.mean+sd), width=.2,
                  position=position_dodge(.9))+
    stat_compare_means(ref.group = rg,label =  "p.signif",method = "wilcox.test",label.y = 7)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
    xlab(unique(x$grp1))
  return(G)
}
#Apply
Lplot <- lapply(List, myfun)
#Wrap plots
wrap_plots(Lplot,nrow = 1)+plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

Output:

[image]

Consider this **update** that takes the values for asterisks stored in a new dataframe:

```
#Create p-vals dataset
List2 <- split(dataset,dataset$grp1)
#p-val function
mypval <- function(x)
{
  y <- compare_means(y~grp2,data = x,method="wilcox.test")
  y <- y[,c('group2', 'group1','p.signif')]
  names(y)<-c('grp2','grp1','p.signif')
  y <- y[y$grp2=='Contrl',]
  y$grp2 <- y$grp1
  y <- rbind(y,data.frame(grp2='Contrl',grp1='',p.signif=''))
  y$grp1 <- unique(x$grp1)
  y$y.mean=7
  return(y)
}
#Apply
dfpvals <- lapply(List2, mypval)
df <- do.call(rbind,dfpvals)
#Plot
ggplot(means.all, aes(x=grp1, y=y.mean, fill=grp2,group=grp2))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y.mean-sd, ymax=y.mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  geom_text(data=df,aes(x=grp1, y=y.mean,group=grp2,label=p.signif),
            position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: When I run a "compare_means" on that same dataset (grp1 = A), it shows there are significant differences (p = 9.70e-15). The code you wrote is doing the wilcoxen test on the means, not the full dataset. Would I just add an aes statement to the "stat_compare_means" function?

Comment: @Schatzi121 Try with that I am not sure how you got the p-val, maybe add that sketch to your question editing it so that we can understand better!

Comment: Okay, I added a line of code running a comparison. I'm pretty sure the "stat_compare_mean" should be able to do it as well, I just need to pass in the full dataset into that as well. Can you help with that? Would I just add another input into the function?

Comment: I'm actually running the code in PowerBI, which runs it each time the page or data are refreshed. So ideally, I'd like it to take as little computing power as possible, cause that will slow it down. I was thinking we could use that same code you have, but pass in the entire datasets, and then run the mean aggregate function within the "myfun" function.

Comment: Storing the results of the test would work, if that can be used to make the asterisks. I'm not sure how to do that. I was hoping it could be an all-in-one with the stat_means function.

Comment: @Schatzi121 I have added an update for you. I hope that can be helpful! It uses your original code!

Comment: I'm not seeing the asterisks when I run your updated code. I just get the plots with nothing on them.

Comment: @Schatzi121 That is very strange, could you please try re starting R and only loading `ggplot2` and `ggpubr` maybe it is a conflict with other package, or are you running on Power BI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224818/discussion-between-schatzi121-and-duck).